# Car mask rules in Italy when living together during holiday

Tags: covid-19, italy, automobiles

We are 5 people from Germany, living in 3 different households. During our holiday in Italy we will live together in one household.

There's a rule in Italy that only 3 people from different households are allowed to ride inside the same car. Does this apply to us?

Comment: what, exactly, does the rule state, in Italian? If it is casa that is different than famiglia.

Comment: I suppose that you with 'during our holiday in Italy we will live together in one household.' mean that you have rented some kind of accomodation, e.g. a house together for your stay in Italy? Wouldn't five people from different households staying together like that already violate other corona related restrictions in Italy? BTW, there are no restrictions in Italy saying that only 3 people from different households can ride in one car. There are regulations on how you must be seated, but depending on the car, you may be more than three people.

Comment: When will you be traveling? Over summer Italy plans on removing many restrictions, so having a date of arrival might help to give a more precise reply.

Comment: Are you all fully vaccinated? If so, it sounds like an awesome trip. If not, please wait until you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the rules applies to you too. The Italian government has stated pretty clearly that all rules apply to both Italian citizens and tourists.

To be more specific, the rules for traveling in a car with non-cohabitant people are the following:

- Nobody can sit in the front seat next to the driver.
- Max 2 people per seat row, on opposite sides of the vehicle (by the windows). If the vehicle has multiple rows, it can carry more people, but only if they can keep a distance of 1m between them (more or less). So vehicles with very small extra rows might only be able to allow for one extra person, instead of two, in those rows.
- Everyone, except kids under 6yo or people with medical reasons, has to wear a mask at all times while in the vehicle.

On a side note: I would double check if 5 people from 3 different households are allowed to live in the same house. I couldn't find anything specific, but I know that for visiting friends you're only allowed to have 2 people (+ kids) go to another household.

Comment: I think that what OP is trying to ask is not if the rules in general applied to tourists, but if they count as three hosueholds (how they live regularly at home) or as just one household (as they plan to temporarliy accomodate during the holidays).

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I believe the address that matters is your residence, the one you can find on your ID. So they would still count from three different households.
Also, if there's any rule against them being in the same house, they would also get in trouble for that in case they get stopped and say they're all living in one house. But as said in the above answer, I'm not sure if there's such a rule for tourists.